# How can return member count of the axis using MDX?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I need to get member count for row and column axis for below query.

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY
    (
        HIERARCHIZE 
        (
            {{DrillDownlevel(([Customer].[Customer Geography]))}}
        ),
        {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]}
    ) DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_TYPE, CHILDREN_CARDINALITY, PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY
    ( 
        HIERARCHIZE 
        (
            {{HIERARCHIZE({({DrillDownlevel(([Date].[Fiscal]))})})}}
        )
    ) DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_TYPE, CHILDREN_CARDINALITY, PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM 
    [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
(
    {[Product].[Product Model Categories].[Category].&[4]}
) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FORMATTED_VALUE
```

The grid will return 7 column and 3 rows from my cube. How can I get these numbers?

Comment: First of all, what is your goal? Where are going to reuse these counts?

Comment: i am implementing paging for my grid using subset, so i need to know total count member on the each axis. For example total member of row axis is 200 means i am displaying 10 member out of 200. 200/10 => 20 pages. I can navigate one page to other page over 20 pages.

Comment: If you get the result, you can fetch its axis size. It's not the MDX task, there is the Axis function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/axis-mdx but if you want to reuse it you're on the wrong way. I'd get the result as an array first, then I'd get the length of the array. Check my blogpost for the python way: http://blog.soft-prestidigitation.com/ssas-via-python.html all you need is len(resource.getAxisTuple(0)) and len(resource.getAxisTuple(1)).